# twainlib how to set scan property when ShowUI = False

Tags: c#, winforms, twain

I use TwainLib.cs to scan in my c# project, [this code](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidA408F1179B1F00D9D1AF6CEF6E29EFD694F79047.aspx?s=button) the same what i start to use

to not show th UI interface of the scanner I use guif.ShowUI = 0 and it work but the image was in lower quality even the barrecode in the image not readed,

I used step by step to found where the dpi or the color bit sended to change them but I failed :/

how I can change scan quality (dpi , color ...) when I scan without showing UI ?

**edit :**

I added iinf.XResolution = 200 but the same result (images with lower resolution)

```
                pxfr.Count = 0;
                IntPtr hbitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

                TwImageInfo iinf = new TwImageInfo();
                iinf.XResolution = 200;
                iinf.YResolution = 200;
                rc = DSiinf(appid, srcds, TwDG.Image, TwDAT.ImageInfo, TwMSG.Get, iinf);
                if (rc != TwRC.Success)
                {
                    CloseSrc();
                    return tifFiles;
                }

                rc = DSixfer(appid, srcds, TwDG.Image, TwDAT.ImageNativeXfer, TwMSG.Get, ref hbitmap);
                if (rc != TwRC.XferDone)
                {
                    CloseSrc();
                    return tifFiles;
                }
```

I want to know where I can insert the dpi resolution if  the manufacturer's user interface is hidden

Comment: juste tell me the reason of the down vote, to change my question, thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use ICAP_XRESOLUTION and ICAP_YRESOLUTION to change the resolution.